# Distinct LISTAGG prior to 19g

Tags: sql, string, oracle, distinct, aggregate-functions

I have query which gives me repeated results when I use LISTAGG, Since my version of Oracle is 18.4, I can't use select DISTINCT with LISTAGG so I am using nested select but can't seem to get it to work.  Can you please let me know what I am missing?
This is the query that works but brings back repeated results:
for example, actionitem_id 1 will show columnmodified of "abc,abc,abc,def,def,def"

```
    SELECT
    ai.actionitem_id,
        LISTAGG( pat.PROPERTYNAME,',')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY pat.PROPERTYNAME) AS columnmodified
FROM propertydefs pd , property_audit_trail pat, rt_actionitem ai
    where pd.bundlename = 'ActionItem'
    and pd.name in ('Action Item Revised Target Date','PVrfy')
    and pd.propertydefid = pat.propertydefid
    and pat.modifydate > to_date('11/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    and pat.resourceid = ai.ACTIONITEM_ID
GROUP BY
    ai.actionitem_id
ORDER BY
    ai.actionitem_id
```

I want actionitem_id 1 to show columnmodified of "abc,def"
so I am trying to run following query but getting following error:
ORA-00904: "PAT"."PROPERTYNAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

```
    SELECT
    ai.actionitem_id,
        (select LISTAGG( pat.PROPERTYNAME,',')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY pat.PROPERTYNAME) AS columnmodified
FROM (select unique pat.PROPERTYNAME
    from propertydefs pd , property_audit_trail pat, rt_actionitem ai
    where pd.bundlename = 'ActionItem'
    and pd.name in ('Action Item Revised Target Date','PVrfy')
    and pd.propertydefid = pat.propertydefid
    and pat.modifydate > to_date('11/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    and pat.resourceid = ai.ACTIONITEM_ID
GROUP BY
    ai.actionitem_id
ORDER BY
    ai.actionitem_id)) PROPERTYNAME
    from rt_actionitem ai
```

can you let me know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  This has been standard SQL syntax since the 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
select actionitem_id, 
    listagg(propertyname,',') within group(order by propertyname) as columnmodified
from (
    select distinct ai.actionitem_id, pat.propertyname
    from propertydefs pd
    inner join property_audit_trail pat on pat.propertydefid = pd.propertydefid
    inner join rt_actionitem ai on ai.actionitem_id = pat.resourceid
    where 
        pd.bundlename = 'actionitem'
        and pd.name in ('action item revised target date','pvrfy') 
        and pat.modifydate > date '2020-11-01'
) t
group by actionitem_id
order by actionitem_id
```

This works by selecting `distinct` action/property tuples in a subquery first, then aggregating by action.

Notes:

- Use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause and join conditions in the `where` clause) are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code. I modified the query accordingly
- Whenever possible, use date literals (`date 'YYYY-MM-DD'`) rather than `to_date()`: this is standard SQL... and is shorter to type

Comment: In the LISTAGG you use the table shortname `pat`, but this table shortname isn't defined in your outer query.

Comment: Hi,  I'm getting following error message:ORA-00904: "PAT"."PROPERTYNAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 58    the inner query works but when I run the full query I get this error

Comment: I see, I changed the "t" after the ")" to "pat" and is now working!  Thanks GMB, Bob and Gordon... sorry about the join syntax, I just need to get used to the new way of things... appreciate the help!!

Comment: @seth: it is not even needed to prefix the columns in the outer query. I fixed the query.

Comment: thanks, that worked also, but not sure how it knows which table actionitem_id and propertyname its referencing, I guess it looks at the inner query?